# CoreMotion drifts

Tags: ios, matrix, core-motion

I'm using `CoreMotion` in my `AR` application to display objects. After some time driving in a car motion manager starts to drift, I guess some errors builds up. This results in objects being displayed in incorrect position. After turning `deviceMotion` off and back on it returns correct values. Is there something I can do to fix this? I'm using `motionManager.deviceMotion?.attitude` to calculate transform in such way:

```
let m = attitude.rotationMatrix
let column1 = vector_double4(m.m11, m.m12, m.m13, 0.0)
let column2 = vector_double4(m.m21, m.m22, m.m23, 0.0)
let column3 = vector_double4(m.m31, m.m32, m.m33, 0.0)
let column4 = vector_double4(0.0,   0.0,   0.0,   1.0)
let cameraMatrix = matrix_double4x4(columns: (column1, column2, column3, column4))    
let projectionCameraMatrix = matrix_multiply(cameraMatrix, projectionMatrix)
```

I have read somewhere that using `motionManager.deviceMotion?.rotationRate` instead of attitude might help. But I don't know how to calculate camera rotation matrix from `rotationRate`. I have tried to use formulas from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix in something like this:

```
guard let g = motionManager.deviceMotion?.rotationRate else { return }
func rotationMatrix(x: Double, y: Double, z: Double) -> CMRotationMatrix {
    let rxc1 = vector_double3(1, 0, 0)
    let rxc2 = vector_double3(0, cos(x), sin(x))
    let rxc3 = vector_double3(0, -sin(x), cos(x))
    let ryc1 = vector_double3(cos(y), 0, -sin(y))
    let ryc2 = vector_double3(0, 1, 0)
    let ryc3 = vector_double3(sin(y), 0, cos(y))
    let rzc1 = vector_double3(cos(z), sin(z), 0)
    let rzc2 = vector_double3(-sin(z), cos(z), 0)
    let rzc3 = vector_double3(0, 0, 1)

    let rx = matrix_double3x3(columns: (rxc1, rxc2, rxc3))
    let ry = matrix_double3x3(columns: (ryc1, ryc2, ryc3))
    let rz = matrix_double3x3(columns: (rzc1, rzc2, rzc3))

    let r = matrix_multiply(matrix_multiply(rx, ry), rz)

    return CMRotationMatrix(m11: r.columns.0.x, m12: r.columns.0.y, m13: r.columns.0.z, m21: r.columns.1.x, m22: r.columns.1.y, m23: r.columns.1.z, m31: r.columns.2.x, m32: r.columns.2.y, m33: r.columns.2.z)
}

let cameraRotationMatrix = rotationMatrix(g.x, y: g.y, z: g.z)
```

But results are wrong. I need to get rotation matrix similar to the one from attitude.

Can someone help me to calculate `rotationMatrix` from `rotationRate`? Or maybe there is some other way to correct this shift after driving for some time.